# Bind an interface using ninject in shared view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

i use ninject to bind  my interfaces to my repository as you can see :

```
  private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<CMSDataContext>().To<CMSDataContext>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<INewsRepository>().To<NewsRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IConfigurationRepository>().To<ConfigurationRepository>().InRequestScope();


        }
```

For example you can see here the structure of `home controller` :

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /fa/Home/

        private IConfigurationRepository _configurationRepository;
        public HomeController(IConfigurationRepository configurationRepository)
        {
            _configurationRepository = configurationRepository;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Configuration = _configurationRepository.GetConfiguration().First();
            return View();
        }

    }
```

But i need to call an interface in my `shared view` i mean `masterpage` as you can see here:

```
<head>
    @{
        IConfigurationRepository _iconfigurationRepository;
    }
    <!-- Basic -->
    <title>@ViewBag.Configuration.Title</title>

    <!-- Define Charset -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

My question is how can i bind this interface in view to its repository i mean `configurationRepository` using ninject ?

Comment: You can use the DependencyResolver from your view

Comment: Could you please give me more details ?

Comment: You should create a model for the view and populate the model values in the controller - the view shouldn't really be going off to an IOC container!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you need to resolve a dependency in your view , you can use the dependencyResolver.

In your razor view:

```
@{
    var config = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IConfigurationRepository >(); 
}
```

In this case, if ninject can resolve constructor-parameters then ninject is the current dependency resolver and you can use in views, filters, controllers,etc.

Comment: Yes, the dependency resolver is an abstraction , and it could be built by a lot of ioc's.